# The Specified blob does not exist - when setting http header

Tags: c#, azure

I have a azure blob that I am uploading. I do a check to see if a file is an svg image then I set the appropriate content type before uploading. I keep getting the following error "The specified blob does not exist". This is my code below:

```
 public async Task UploadAssetsAsync(Func<GridFSFileInfo, string> prefixSelector, List<GridFSFileInfo> files, Func<GridFSFileInfo, Task<Stream>> streamOpener, Func<string, Task> progressAction)
        {
            if (flyersContainerClient == null)
                throw new Exception("Container client not initialized. Please initialize before doing blob operations.");
            var q = new Queue<Task<Response<BlobContentInfo>>>();
            progressAction?.Invoke($"{files.Count}");
            foreach (var f in files)
            {
                var pathPrefix = prefixSelector(f);
                var blobClient = flyersContainerClient.GetBlobClient($"{pathPrefix}/{f.Filename.Replace("_copy", "")}");
                IDictionary<string, string> metadata = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                var blobhttpheader = new BlobHttpHeaders();
                if (f.Filename.EndsWith("svg"))
                {

                    blobhttpheader.ContentType = "image/svg+xml";
                    blobClient.SetHttpHeaders(blobhttpheader);
                    


                }

                var stream = await streamOpener(f);
               
                q.Enqueue(blobClient.UploadAsync(stream, new BlobUploadOptions { HttpHeaders = blobhttpheader, TransferOptions = new Azure.Storage.StorageTransferOptions { MaximumConcurrency = 8, InitialTransferSize = 50 * 1024 * 1024 } }));
               

            }

            await Task.WhenAll(q);
        }
```

What I have noticed is that when I am not setting httpheaders by commenting out the if statement and removing `HttpHeaders = blobhttpheader,` I can upload my blob. Can someone help me with how I am setting my header and why its incorrect?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you are getting this error is because `blobClient.SetHttpHeaders(blobhttpheader);` is making an HTTP request to set the blob headers and considering the blob doesn't exist till now, you are getting `Blob Not Found` error (correctly so).

To fix the error, simply remove this line of code. It is also not needed because the HTTP headers will be set when you upload the blob.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone have issues with the contenttype is set to "application/octet-stream" and want to set eg "image/jpeg". The command "await client.SetHttpHeadersAsync" must be **after** the upload - doh :-)

```
var client = container.GetBlobClient(fileName);

            //upload file to blob
            var cancellationToken = new System.Threading.CancellationToken();

            await using (Stream? data = blob.OpenReadStream())
            await client.UploadAsync(data, true, cancellationToken);

            switch (fileName)
            {
                case string a when a.Contains(".png"):
                    await client.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/png" });
                    break;
                case string b when b.Contains(".jpg"):
                    await client.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/jpeg" });
                    break;
                case string c when c.Contains(".jpeg"):
                    await client.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/jpeg" });
                    break;
                case string d when d.Contains(".gif"):
                    await client.SetHttpHeadersAsync(new BlobHttpHeaders { ContentType = "image/gif" });
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
```